# Wait for a thread to die in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-2.4, ruby-2.5

It appears that, in Ruby 2.4 and 2.5, threads don't die as soon as you invoke `#kill` on them. This code snippet will print *Not dead* a few times:

```
thread = Thread.new { loop {} }
thread.kill
puts "Not dead" while thread.alive?
```

I'd like to block execution of the main thread until the secondary thread is killed. I tried using `thread.join.kill`, but of course this blocks the main thread because the thread's loop never terminates.

How can I ensure that a thread is killed before the main thread continues?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out; you can still `#join` the thread after killing it, so you can use `thread.kill.join` to block until the thread dies.

This code never prints *Not dead*:

```
thread = Thread.new { loop {} }
thread.kill.join
puts "Not dead" while thread.alive?
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `join` blocks the calling thread until the thread's been terminated properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this:

```
thread = Thread.new { loop {} }
thread.kill
sleep 0.001 while thread.alive?
```

This is how I terminate threads in my [ThreadPool](https://github.com/zold-io/zold/blob/master/lib/zold/thread_pool.rb).